# JavaScript Maximum Table Size

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've run into a bit of a problem with a webpage I'm developing.  Here's the general structure of the page I'm having trouble with for a bit of background:

- There is a form where the user selects from four checkboxes and a dropdown menu.  When at least one checkbox has been selected and the dropdown menu has been chosen from, I use jQuery to generate a "popup window," which is really just an iframe that I had set to be hidden initially but then becomes visible once the input is valid.  This all works just fine.
- Within the iframe, I have an interactive table whose rows are dynamically determined by the user's form input.  This is the table I'm having a problem with.

I want the table to have a "maximum height," so to speak.  In other words, I want the table's rows to print out normally until the total height of the table reaches a certain point.  At that point, I want the table to become scrollable, if you will, much in the same way that a textarea becomes scrollable when enough text has been put into it (its overall height doesn't change but you can scroll through it).

I am open to any suggestions as long as they only involve HTML, CSS, PHP, JavaScript, and/or jQuery.  If you need any clarifications, don't hesitate to ask--it wasn't too easy to put all this into words so I would understand if I wasn't clear enough.

Comment: Put the `table` in a `div`, and give the `div` a `max-height` and `overflow: scroll`?

Comment: I'm not sure about any real solution but couldn't you just throw that `table` inside a `div style="height:{whatever};overflow:scroll"` (inside the iframe)? EDIT: Thomas already typed exactly the same as me above there :)

Comment: Here's an implementation of David Thomas' answer http://jsfiddle.net/8znuH/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your CSS, apply `height: YOUR_MAX_HEIGHT` and `overflow-y: scroll` to your table.  This should be a good start to what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: This is actually exactly what I was looking to achieve.  Thanks!

Comment: This won't work when the table is not as tall as `YOUR_MAX_HEIGHT`?

Comment: @JackRadcliffe if `height` does not work for you try `max-height`.

Comment: Neither height or max-height work, unless you change your table to be `display: block` or `inline-block` http://jsfiddle.net/8znuH/5/ Inline elements can't be given heights

Comment: @JuanMendes so your suggesting wrapping the table in a `div` since it is a block element and applying the css to it instead?

Comment: @marteljn From my example, you can see that you don't necessarily need to wrap the table with a div. It does make it easier to apply padding so that scrollbars aren't over the content, though